# How to check if a given string is a part of any given Enum in Java?

Tags: java, enums

I have two different enums and i want to be able to output whether a given
string is a part of a enum collection. this is my code:

```
public class Check {
    public enum Filter{SIZE, DATE, NAME};
    public enum Action{COPY, DELETE, REMOVE};

    public boolean isInEnum(String value, Enum e){
        // check if string value is a part of a given enum
        return false;
    }

    public void main(){
        String filter = "SIZE";
        String action = "DELETE";
                // check the strings
        isInEnum(filter, Filter);
        isInEnum(action, Action);
    }
}
```

eclipse says that in the last two lines "Filter can't be resolved to a variable" but
apart from that it seems that the Enum param in the function "isInEnum" is wrong.

Something is very wrong here can anyone help?

Comment: You got that right :) enum is just a regular class, you can't mention its name like that. Enum mebers are instances of their enum, not the enum as a whole.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The simplest (and usually most efficient) way is as follows:

```
public <E extends Enum<E>> boolean isInEnum(String value, Class<E> enumClass) {
  for (E e : enumClass.getEnumConstants()) {
    if(e.name().equals(value)) { return true; }
  }
  return false;
}
```

and then you call `isInEnum(filter, Filter.class)`.

Comment: How about `enumClass.getMethod("valueOf", String.class).invoke(null, value)`?

Comment: this did the trick but the syntax is crazy.. need to learn a bit about those generics

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik why use Reflection when you are looping through the elements anyway and you can use `e.valueOf(value)` instead. Also note when using valueOf you have to catch `IllegalArgumentException` if the name doesn't exist and `NullPointerException` if string is null

Comment: can you explain the <E extends Enum<E>> syntax?

Comment: But `e` is an enum instance -- I'm talking about calling the static `valueOf` method that every enum class has. That's the way you normally do this code, when reflection is not necessary.

Comment: @tom The `enum Filter` is actually a `public class Filter extends Enum<Filter>`. That's how all the methods in class Enum work for every subclass.

Comment: I actually had a huge argument about this on another SO question, and it turns out that the above implementation, with the for loop, is almost always faster than the `try/catch` you have to do with `Enum.valueOf` if you don't know if the string is one of the enum's values.  I have hard numbers to demonstrate it, if you like.

Comment: @Ozzy But in that case, you see that you wouldn't have to iterate? I take the point about exceptions, that's a nasty one. The whole thing would perform worse than the solution given.

Comment: @LouisWasserman hard numbers are always great, but I know my way must be worse. Your solution involves no reflective calls and no exception handling, both expensive operations, and in the end my solution does that same iteration (possibly optimized via hashCode?). If I didn't need exception handling, I might have preferred it since it would have been a one-liner.

Comment: Actually, I believe `valueOf` keeps a global cache of `Map<String, Object>` for each enum type, which makes it constant-time -- but the exception is just so expensive that it dominates the cost in almost all cases.

Comment: Maybe your approach could be improved by getting at that map reflectively.

Comment: Ugh.  Maybe, but what an evil, awkward approach.

Comment: You can write it even shorter (Java 8) as: 

`public static <E extends Enum<E>> boolean isInEnum(String value, Class<E> enumClass) {
  return Arrays.asList(enumClass.getEnumConstants()).stream().anyMatch(e -> e.name().equals(value));
 }`

Answer (score 11):

If you don't mind using Apache commons lang3 library you can use the following code:

```
EnumUtils.isValidEnum(Filter.class, filter)
```

According to the [docs](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/) :

> This method differs from Enum.valueOf(java.lang.Class, java.lang.String) in that it does not throw an exception for an invalid enum name.

Comment: i will mind.. the problem is just to add a trivial utility , we need to add a new dependency...  dependencies are costly... its like buying a car just because you found a car key

Comment: @Stunner Fair enough, I wouldn't necessarily advise adding a dependency just for that. But in a project where you already use this library anyway, it's a comfortable solution.

Answer (score 7):

Here is a Java 8/streams version of Louis Wasserman's answer. (You can also put this method directly into the Enum class, and remove one of the parameters)

```
public boolean isInEnum(String value, Class<E> enumClass) {
    return Arrays.stream(enumClass.getEnumConstants()).anyMatch(e -> e.name().equals(value));
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

I don't have enough points to comment on Simon Tower's answer directly, but here is the method for the second way he mentioned that goes directly in the enum class itself:

```
 public static boolean isInEnum(String value) {
     return Arrays.stream(EnumClassNameGoesHere.values()).anyMatch(e -> e.name().equals(value));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Avoid using a loop to do the validation.

I would suggest using `valueOf`. This method is built-in to enums, and might be considered for compile time optimization.

This would be like similar to implementing a static `Map<String,EnumType>` to optimize the lookup, an other consideration you can take.

Drawback is that you would have to use the exception handling mechanism to catch a non-enum value.

Example

```
public enum DataType {
  //...
  static public boolean has(String value) {
    if (value== null) return false;
    try { 
        // In this implementation - I want to ignore the case
        // if you want otherwise ... remove .toUpperCase()
        return valueOf(value.toUpperCase()); 
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException x) { 
        // the uggly part ...
        return false;
    }
  }
}
```

Also note that with above type implementation, your code looks much cleaner when calling. Your main would now look something like:

```
public void main(){
    String filter = "SIZE";
    String action = "DELETE";

    // ...

    if (Filter.has(filter) && Action.has(action)) {
      // Appropriate action
    }
}
```

Then the other mentioned option is to use a static Map. You can employ such an approach to cache all sort of indexing based on other properties too. In below  example, I allow each enum value to have a list of alias names. The lookup index in this case will be case insensitive, by forcing to uppercase.

```
public enum Command {
  DELETE("del","rm","remove"),
  COPY("cp"),
  DIR("ls");

  private static final Map<String,Command> ALIAS_MAP = new HashMap<String,Command>();
  static {
    for (Command type:Command.values()) {
      ALIAS_MAP.put(type.getKey().toUpper(),type);
      for (String alias:type.aliases) ALIAS_MAP.put(alias.toUpper(),type);
    }
  }

  static public boolean has(String value) {
    return ALIAS_MAP.containsKey(value.toUpper());
  }

  static public Command fromString(String value) {
    if (value == null) throw new NullPointerException("alias null");
    Command command = ALIAS_MAP.get(value);
    if (command == null) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Not an alias: "+value);
    return command;
  }

  private List<String> aliases;
  private Command(String... aliases) {
    this.aliases = Arrays.asList(aliases);
  }
}
```

Comment: Note the comment posts about overhead from the exceptions. They were hidden from me when I first posted.

Comment: I was looking at another similar topic. One user mentioned that in such a case the JIT compiler would optimize the exception overhead away. The overhead is only noticeable while debugging because of all the instrumentation.

Answer (score 0):

This can also be done as follows:

```
public boolean isInEnum(String value, Enum e){
    return Enums.getIfPresent(e.class, value).isPresent();
}
```

More details can be found [here](https://guava.dev/releases/19.0/api/docs/index.html?com/google/common/base/Enums.html).